# Close session AVCaptureSession and open view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, avcapturesession

How to make the camera close after the photo and the controller opens.I want to close the camera after the session, tell me what method it is. I watched a lot of articles here and wrote it down, it seems to be correct. But I don’t see the effect.
Я записал этот метод в `viewDidDissaper.` Tell me how to specify correctly so that after I take a photo, it opens `ViewController`

```
 import UIKit
    import AVFoundation
    import PhotoEditorSDK
    import Photos
    
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        
       
        @IBOutlet weak var ImageGray: UIImageView!
        
     
    
        var session = AVCaptureSession()
            var camera : AVCaptureDevice?
            var cameraPreviewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
            var cameraCaptureOutput : AVCapturePhotoOutput?
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
           // let grayImage = openCVWrapper.toGray(ImageGray.image!)
           // ImageGray.image = grayImage
      
        }
        
    
        func stopCaptureSession() {
    
            if let inputs = session.inputs as? [AVCaptureDeviceInput] {
                for input in inputs {
                    session.removeInput(input)
                }
                let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController")
                self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                
            }
        }
        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(animated)
            // Setup your camera here...
            initializeCaptureSession()
        }
        override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
                super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
             stopCaptureSession()
            
        }
        @IBAction func cameraShot(_ sender: Any) {
            
            takePicture()
         
        }
        
            
        
        func initializeCaptureSession() {
                
            session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.high
            camera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)
                
                do {
                    let cameraCaptureInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera!)
                    cameraCaptureOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
                    
                    session.addInput(cameraCaptureInput)
                    session.addOutput(cameraCaptureOutput!)
                    
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                
                cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
            cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
                cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = view.bounds
            cameraPreviewLayer?.connection!.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                
                view.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer!, at: 0)
                
                session.startRunning()
            }
        func takePicture() {
               let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
               settings.flashMode = .auto
               cameraCaptureOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
           }
        @IBAction func AddGray(_ sender: Any) {
              
            let grayImage = openCVWrapper.toGray(ImageGray.image!)
            ImageGray.image = grayImage
            ImageGray.transform = ImageGray.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2)) //90
            
            
            
        }
        
        @IBAction func addColor(_ sender: Any) {
      
                
            }
    
            
       
    }
    
    
    extension ViewController : AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
        
        func photoOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhoto previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {
            
            if let unwrappedError = error {
                print(unwrappedError.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                
                if let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer, let dataImage = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewPhotoSampleBuffer) {
                    
                    if let finalImage = UIImage(data: dataImage) {
                        
                        self.ImageGray.image = finalImage
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What currently happens after you capture photo in `didFinishProcessingPhoto` ?

Comment: displayed in UIImageGray And the camera continues to work.